# How to connect a COBOL program to an Oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, unix, cobol, mainframe

How can my COBOL program running, on a mainframe platform, connect and access an Oracle database running on different Unix platform?

Comment: Is anyone else at your site doing this? If not, talk to your technical staff. Sysprogs, DBAs, Network people, etc. If they don't know, then someone needs to talk to Oracle, and the exact solution arrived at will involve all of the above people. And only perhaps involve you.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle have a product for embedding SQL calls in COBOL; it's the Pro*COBOL pre-compiler.  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28428/toc.htm)

The snag is, the Pro*COBOL program must reside on the Oracle server.  So, given your architecture, you need to make remote calls.  It's been a long time since I used COBOL (literally more than two decades) but the thing I remember the most was that functionality varied strongly across different flavours.

If you are using a flavour based on the  COBOL-85 compiler (or later) which has the EXTERNAL extension then you're in luck, because you can write your own remote calls.  [Here's a CICS example](http://documentation.softwareag.com/webmethods/entirex/exx733/cobWrapper/cobWrapper_writeAppsRpc.htm).  Otherwise you might need to buy something.  ETS sell a product called Cobol-RPC: [find out more](http://showcase.netins.net/web/etsinc/cobolrpc.html) (no warranty is implied or intended).